# How would I display this in main(String[] args) and how do I hook up these classes and/or constructors in xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring, validation, target

I am trying to validate if a String has a number associated with it, and rejecting the value if it has a number.  It is my first time using Spring Validation, and I have struggled for days with getting it all set up properly.  I want the string to print out if it doesn't contain a number, but be rejected by the validator if it does.  I am also unsure about the paramater being the value of target.  I am unsure of how all of that works.  Here is what I have so far:

```
@Component
public class StringValidator implements Validator
{   
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) 
    {
        return Main.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors)
    {
        //the 2nd parameter in ValidationUtils needs to be the string the validator takes in, which should be a set value from Main...?
        Main main = (Main) target;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, String.valueOf(main), AppConstants.NULL_ERROR_MSG);

        if(!errors.hasErrors())
        {
            boolean containsNbr = false;
            for(char c : String.valueOf(main).toCharArray())
            {
                if(Character.isDigit(c))
                {
                    containsNbr = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(containsNbr)
            {
            errors.rejectValue(String.valueOf(main), AppConstants.NUMBERS_ERROR_MSG);
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(main));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

     <context:component-scan base-package="com.imports.validationexample"/>

     <bean id="main" class="com.imports.validationexample.application" />

     <bean id ="springValidator" class="com.imports.validationexample.validation.StringValidator" />

     <bean id="main" class="com.imports.validationexample.application.main">
        <property name="string" value="Forty8"/>
     </bean>

     <bean id="validate" class="org.springframework.validation.Validator">
        <constructor-arg ref="Validator"/>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

I can't seem to hook it up properly, and am unsure how to represent it in my Main class.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to do. I see you are injecting a string into a class main (which seems to be a `public static void main()` class). Do you expect Spring to validate that string you are injecting or?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach (maybe it can be improved):
app-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="stringValidator" class="com.foo.bar.StringValidator" />

<bean id="myStringHoldingBean" class="com.foo.bar.MyStringHoldingBean">
    <property name="string" value="Faulty m3ssage" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Your main class:

```
package com.foo.bar;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml");

        MyStringHoldingBean bean = (MyStringHoldingBean) ctx.getBean("myStringHoldingBean");
        Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(bean, "myStringHoldingBean");

        Validator validator = (Validator)ctx.getBean("stringValidator");

        ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(validator, bean, errors);
        if (errors.hasErrors()) { System.out.println("ERRORS"); }

    }

}
```

MyStringHoldingBean:

```
package com.foo.bar;

public class MyStringHoldingBean {
    private String string;

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

StringValidator:

```
package com.foo.bar;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public class StringValidator implements Validator {
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return MyStringHoldingBean.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        MyStringHoldingBean main = (MyStringHoldingBean) target;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "string", "Not null string, please!");

        if (!errors.hasErrors()) {
            boolean containsNbr = false;
            for (char c : main.getString().toCharArray()) {
                if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    containsNbr = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (containsNbr) {
                errors.rejectValue("string", "String contains numbers!");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println(main.getString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <spring.framework.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Spring Validation is about validating beans, so this is why I put that "string" inside a class (MyStringHoldingBean).

Comment: I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException:  org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:421)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:652)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:346)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:618)
... 7 more

Comment: The error you get is just a missing jar in your classpath, maybe my pom will help you.